# AngularJS promise catch 401

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am using a very basic angularJS code for a user login like this:

```
[...]
this.login = function(email, password) {
    promise = $http.post('/login',
            {
                'email': email,
                'password': password
            });
    promise.then(function(response){
            console.log("success");
        }).catch(function(response){
            console.log("catch");
        }).finally(function(response){
            console.log("finally");
        });
    return promise;
};
[...]
```

When the REST API generates an response with code 200, then the client console will log `success finally` and the user is logged in.
When the server generates a response with a 403 or 500 code, the console will print out `catch finally`.

But when the response will be with a 401, angular does not print out anything. The console will stay empty, only with the `POST http://127.0.0.1/login 401 (Unauthorized)` hint. But no `success` or `catch` as output. And no `finally` neither.

In my project, 403 will be catched globally with a `$rootScope.$on('event:auth-forbidden', function(r) {...});`. That's why the REST Server will only throw 404 when something is not found, 403 when the user has no permission and/or is not logged in and 401 only if the login failed.

So how can I catch a 401 on `$http`?
Isn't the `.then` promise only for return 200 and the `.catch` for every other return != 200?

I am using angularJS v1.6.4 with angular-http-auth v1.5.0.

Comment: This old article i think is a good reference for this. You can chain .success .error instad of then. Or else. You could use .then and inspect response object, it should have a status code property indicating if you should reject or resolve the promise https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service

Comment: Do you use `angular-http-auth` module?

Comment: ... or have any global `$http` interceptors registered?

Comment: yes, I have `angular-http-auth` with version v1.5.0. I am using the `http-auth-interceptor` module in order to use `authService.loginConfirmed(response.data);` in the `then` chain of a successful login. But besides that I only listen on `event:auth-forbidden`, `event:auth-loginConfirmed` and `event:auth-loginRequired` with `$rootScope.$on(...);`.

Comment: And `.success` or `.error` are not anymore available in my angular version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `angular-http-auth` module intercepts the responses with status 401 or 403:

> The `$http` interceptor does the following: the configuration object (this is the requested URL, payload and parameters) of every HTTP 401 response is buffered and everytime it happens, the event:auth-loginRequired message is broadcasted from `$rootScope`.

To disable the 401 interceptor set `ignoreAuthModule: true`:

> Sometimes you might not want the interceptor to intercept a request even if one returns 401 or 403. In a case like this you can add `ignoreAuthModule: true` to the request config.

The module creates a new promise in pending state for 401 status. The response is buffered and you have a chance to call `authService.loginConfirmed()` or `authService.loginCancelled()` functions. The first one retries all the requests previously failed due to HTTP 401 response. When the second one cancels all pending requests previously failed and buffered due to HTTP 401 response.

[Docs](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth#manual)

Comment: ok, that is interesting. If the REST throws a 403, the `event:auth-forbidden` AND the `$http.catch` are triggert. But if the RESt throws a 401, only the `vent:auth-loginRequired` is triggert, but the `$http.catch` is not. Why is the catch not working? It will only trigger on 403 or 500...

Comment: Good question, according [this code](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/master/src/http-auth-interceptor.js#L59) in the case of response with a status 401, new promise is created and returned. The `catch` callback is not called because this new promise is in pending state.

Comment: interesting ... but only the 403 is creating a new promise that can be catched. the 401 just interrupts. Only with the `ignoreAuthModule` it will go in `catch` and `finally`. That is very confusing ... no `finally` on the promise possible when the REST throws a 401.